# WebAPI in C#: Why I cannot call an async task in a public class from another public class?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call an async task in a public class from another public class, but this is failing. The problem is that SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync in [public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials] "does not exist in the current context". The private async task is in AccountController.cs. How can I call it properly?

I need to keep the task ideally in the AccountController.cs as it has dependencies to UserManager.xxx

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated!

ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs:

```
namespace BlaBla.Providers
{
    public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private readonly string _publicClientId;

        public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
        {
            if (publicClientId == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
            }

            _publicClientId = publicClientId;
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            // if email not confirmed prevent log-in

            if (!await userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
            {
                // resend confirmation mail if not confirmed, but SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync cannot be found !!!
                string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Resend: Confirm your Blabla account");

                context.SetError("email_not_confirmed", "Please confirm email to be able to log-in.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
               OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }

        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
            if (context.ClientId == null)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
        {
            if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
            {
                Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

                if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
                {
                    context.Validated();
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "userName", userName }
            };
            return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
        }

    }
}
```

AccountController.cs:

```
namespace Blabla.Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
            ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

<..removed lines..>

        // added task for re-send functionality, but not reachable from ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs !!!

        private async Task<string> SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(string userID, string subject)
        {
            string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID);

            var callbackUrl = Url.Link("Default", new
            {
                Controller = "api/Account",
                Action = "ConfirmEmail",
                userId = userID,
                code = code
            });

            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userID, subject,
               "Please confirm your Blabla account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return callbackUrl;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want to call a *private* member in a public class without instantiating an instance of that class? Because that is what you have coded and thought. Can you see the flaw already? I'd say move the code to call to another class and have both the controller and the auth. provider use that class.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Any code sample how I can solve that? Maybe then it´s more clear for me.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look into `Dependency Injection`

Comment: You just need to learn what private and public means... not sure how you got this far without knowing that?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: Hehe, I am also wondering how I got this far :)) Joke aside, I was pretty sure that I have changed it to public in the last version already but obviously not. Thank you!!!